# Chrome adding it's own timeline to videojs player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use videojs in my react application. I made it responsive but the problem is chrome adds it's owm timeline(control bar) to the player. I want to see the default videojs control bar. Here is code and jsfiddle of player

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
<video controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">

  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.video-container{
  background: red;
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.section {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1gsrsu5/2/

How can I solve this?

Comment: Remove the `controls` attribute from your video tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-controls

Comment: (your 'controls' attribute is fine.) But, you do need a class attribute and a data-setup attribute as shown in the 2nd video tag example here:  http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

To your video tag, add attributes for 'id' and 'class', so it looks like
this:

```
<video id="videoID" class="video-js  vjs-default-skin" controls>
</video>
```

[ See:  http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html ]

Below the video tag, add one line of javascript, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var myPlayer = videojs('videoID');
</script>
```

[ Once you click on the default 'big arrow', an auto-disappearing  videojs controlBar will appear. ]

One last (optional) tweak, if like me, you don't like the negative valued 'remaining-time', you can add some CSS code (up in the header, just below
your link to videojs's CSS code, to hide it and
unhide the more-commonly-used "time / duration" info):

```
<style>
    .video-js .vjs-current-time { display: block; }
    .video-js .vjs-time-divider { display: block; }
    .video-js .vjs-duration { display: block; }
    .video-js .vjs-remaining-time { display: none; }
</style>
```

That's not formally documented anywhere...I figured that out, after stumbling upon:  https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2507